# Does QB Online SDK support 64 bit?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I just want to make sure that, does QB Online SDK support 64 bit?
I am using `IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3 5.3.0` in my code and doing OAuth2 authentication using SDK Code. So, QuickBooks SDK dlls have support for both 32 and 64 bit or only 32 bit system?

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for SO but -- anything for QuickBooks _Online_ supports both 64- and 32- bit (because all they are doing is just REST API calls out to a remote server). 

(Note that that SDK is only for QuickBooks _Online_. If you're trying to integrate with a desktop/Windows version of QuickBooks or using the Web Connector, then you're using the wrong SDK)

Comment: hello Keith Palmer Jr. Thanks for your Comment on this... I have another question, My use-case is, I want to create invoice in my site, and store all invoice, customer, items details in my Local SQL Database, now i want to sync all these data to my company's QuickBooks Online Account?
Is that Possible to sync from local data to Quickbooks Online? If so, How?

Comment: I have seen Create Invoice REST API Web Method, but i don't want to use that, is there any direct method for Syncing?

Comment: You can sync data from your application to QuickBooks Online using the REST API. Read the docs: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting